# What is the reason that there is no primary key in a associative entity?

Tags: many-to-many, relational-database, primary-key, entity-relationship, erd

I have the following ERD diagram:
[image]

What is the difference between a many-to-many relationship and an associative entity?

Why is there no PK in the `Teaching` entity?

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What published DB design textbook/reference are you following? What definitions? What method? What are its steps? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck? You essentially ask us to (re)write a textbook for an unidentified method & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Every entity (class) (table) has a PK.

Comment: Your diagram appears not to show key(s) for any entity. (Although I'm not getting why some entities have a filled bullet -- like `ID` for `People`. The circled `ToHire` has a filled `StartDate`.) So why are you claiming " there is no primary key in an associative entity"? Every entity has a PK, as @philipxy says. Your diagram isn't showing them clearly.

Comment: Seems maybe you are having difficulties reading that (kind of) ERD. Seems maybe you are trying to ask about the ERD rather than just the design it's from or describes. But this post is not clear about just what it is trying to ask. Including, why/how you are 1st stuck, given what, with what goal. Also ERD conventions are specific to a particular method/presentation/reference. We can guess at how to read this but that is inappropriate. You should identify where you got it & what that source says about how to read/write it and other relevant aspects of the design process.

Answer (score 0):

A **many-to-many relationship** means that each entity involved may be related to several entities on the other side. For example, in your model, a `School` may be related to several `Teacher` via the relationship `To hire`, and a `Teacher` may be related to several `School`. In an RDBMS, such a relationship is usually [implemented with](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab#:%7E:text=Many%2Dto%2DMany%20Relationships,-So%20how%20do&text=A%20joining%20table%20is%20a,of%20these%20other%20two%20tables.) a "joining table" (also called "bridging table", or ["association table"](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html)).

Despite the fact that nowadays, many people tend to use attributes for relationships, relationships are not supposed to have their own attributes, according to the definition [laid down by Peter Chen](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1499402.1499421) (who invented ERD):

> An attribute is a mapping from an entity set (or a relationship set) to a value set (or a group of value sets).

If you'd want a relationship to have attributes, you 'd better use an [**associative entity**](https://vertabelo.com/blog/chen-erd-notation/), which is at the same time a relationship and an entity.  In your example, it's the case of `Teaching`. Associative entities are also implemented using a joining table (even if it's not many-to-many), and this is why there's sometimes confusion.

Regarding keys, the principle laid down by Chen applies:

> Since a relationship is identified by the involved entities, the primary key of a relationship can be represented by the primary keys of the involved entities.

However, sometimes we want the same entities to be related several time. For example a `Teacher` is related to a `High School`, and could (not in your diagram unfortunately) teach different disciplines in the the same high school  Entities have a unique identity, and so do associative entities.  This is why, you could decide to give a [surrogate primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) to the associative entity, instead of relying on a composite primary key.